# fs problem when using google-apis in Astro project

Tags: google-sheets, google-apis-explorer, node.js-fs, astrojs

In my astro project, I'm trying to build an api end point in order to make a POST request to the google sheets api. To achieve this, I've installed the google-apis package.

The problem in question is when the localhost is initialised, the following error is printed out as follows:

```
  astro  v2.10.14 started in 257ms

  ┃ Local    http://localhost:3000/
  ┃ Network  use --host to expose

✘ [ERROR] Failed to resolve entry for package "fs". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json. [plugin vite:dep-pre-bundle]

    node_modules/.pnpm/google-auth-library@9.0.0/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/identitypoolclient.js:18:19:
      18 │ const fs = require("fs");
         ╵                    ~~~~

  This error came from the "onResolve" callback registered here:

    node_modules/.pnpm/esbuild@0.18.20/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1292:20:
      1292 │       let promise = setup({
           ╵                     ^

    at setup (file:///Users/jcbraz/Projects/hugo-araujo-website/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@4.4.9_@types+node@20.5.7/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:39921:19)
    at handlePlugins (/Users/jcbraz/Projects/hugo-araujo-website/node_modules/.pnpm/esbuild@0.18.20/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1292:21)
    at buildOrContextImpl (/Users/jcbraz/Projects/hugo-araujo-website/node_modules/.pnpm/esbuild@0.18.20/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:978:5)
    at Object.buildOrContext (/Users/jcbraz/Projects/hugo-araujo-website/node_modules/.pnpm/esbuild@0.18.20/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:786:5)
    at /Users/jcbraz/Projects/hugo-araujo-website/node_modules/.pnpm/esbuild@0.18.20/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:2186:68
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.context (/Users/jcbraz/Projects/hugo-araujo-website/node_modules/.pnpm/esbuild@0.18.20/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:2186:27)
    at Object.context (/Users/jcbraz/Projects/hugo-araujo-website/node_modules/.pnpm/esbuild@0.18.20/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:2026:58)
    at prepareEsbuildOptimizerRun (file:///Users/jcbraz/Projects/hugo-araujo-website/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@4.4.9_@types+node@20.5.7/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:45967:35)

✘ [ERROR] Failed to resolve entry for package "fs". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json. [plugin vite:dep-pre-bundle]

    node_modules/.pnpm/google-auth-library@9.0.0/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:18:19:
      18 │ const fs = require("fs");

...
```

After some research, I've tried to change the Vite section in the astro.config.mjs file as described in the following issue post: https://github.com/nuxt/vite/issues/160

```
import { defineConfig } from "astro/config";
import react from "@astrojs/react";
import { loadEnv } from "vite";
import rollupPluginNodeBuiltins from 'rollup-plugin-node-builtins';
const { GOOGLE_SHEETS_API, SHEET_ID } = loadEnv(process.env.NODE_ENV, process.cwd(), "");

import tailwind from "@astrojs/tailwind";

// https://astro.build/config
export default defineConfig({
  integrations: [
    react(),
    tailwind({
      applyBaseStyles: false,
    }),
  ],
  vite: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        fs: rollupPluginNodeBuiltins
      }
    }
  }
});
```

After the following change, I still got the following error when spinning up the localhost:

```
    astro  v2.10.14 started in 298ms

  ┃ Local    http://localhost:3000/
  ┃ Network  use --host to expose

✘ [ERROR] Could not read from file: /Users/jcbraz/Projects/hugo-araujo-website/[object Object]

    node_modules/.pnpm/google-auth-library@9.0.0/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/identitypoolclient.js:18:19:
      18 │ const fs = require("fs");
         ╵                    ~~~~
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use node libraries directly inside the astro file.

If you are using fs only for read operations,
instead of "fs" you can use [`Astro.glob()`](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/api-reference/#astroglob).

If you need to do write since astro is a static site generator you need to switch to ssr mode and use the [astrojs/node](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/integrations-guide/node/) adapter.

Comment: This isn't exactly the case. I have found I am able import and use some packages, while others fail. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77621581/cannot-create-astro-builds-using-other-modules-mysql-etc