# Astro static build fails when using (certain) node packages

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, astrojs

I'm attempting to build an astro project using dynamic data from MySQL. I'm importing the data from a local MySQL in a module (using [nodejs-mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodejs-mysql)), which I import into `[post].astro` and `[...page].astro` (for pagination).

The site runs fine with `astro dev` but `astro build` results in the following error. However, if I replace the dynamic content with a fetch call to use random data the build works fine. Is there something wrong with the way I'm importing the [nodejs-mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodejs-mysql) module?

```
error   mysql.getInstance is not a function
  File:
    /Users/me/Sites/test/Astrojs/astro-starter/node_modules/astro/dist/core/render/route-cache.js:29:27
  Code:
    28 |   }
    > 29 |   staticPaths = await mod.getStaticPaths({
         |                           ^
      30 |     // Q: Why the cast?
      31 |     // A: So users downstream can have nicer typings, we have to make some sacrifice in our internal typings, which necessitate a cast here
      32 |     paginate: generatePaginateFunction(route),
  Stacktrace:
TypeError: mysql.getInstance is not a function
    at Module.getStaticPaths (file:///Users/me/Sites/test/Astrojs/astro-starter/dist/chunks/pages/_post__1e134298.mjs:15:20)
    at callGetStaticPaths (file:///Users/me/Sites/test/Astrojs/astro-starter/node_modules/astro/dist/core/render/route-cache.js:29:27)
    at getPathsForRoute (file:///Users/me/Sites/test/Astrojs/astro-starter/node_modules/astro/dist/core/build/generate.js:288:33)
    at generatePage (file:///Users/me/Sites/test/Astrojs/astro-starter/node_modules/astro/dist/core/build/generate.js:253:23)
    at async generatePages (file:///Users/me/Sites/test/Astrojs/astro-starter/node_modules/astro/dist/core/build/generate.js:167:9)
    at async staticBuild (file:///Users/me/Sites/test/Astrojs/astro-starter/node_modules/astro/dist/core/build/static-build.js:86:7)
    at async AstroBuilder.build (file:///Users/me/Sites/test/Astrojs/astro-starter/node_modules/astro/dist/core/build/index.js:134:5)
    at async AstroBuilder.run (file:///Users/me/Sites/test/Astrojs/astro-starter/node_modules/astro/dist/core/build/index.js:165:7)
    at async build (file:///Users/me/Sites/test/Astrojs/astro-starter/node_modules/astro/dist/core/build/index.js:44:3)
    at async build (file:///Users/me/Sites/test/Astrojs/astro-starter/node_modules/astro/dist/cli/build/index.js:21:3)
    at async runCommand (file:///Users/me/Sites/test/Astrojs/astro-starter/node_modules/astro/dist/cli/index.js:116:7)
    at async cli (file:///Users/me/Sites/test/Astrojs/astro-starter/node_modules/astro/dist/cli/index.js:144:5)
```

```js
/* /src/pages/blog/[post].astro */

import * as MySQLData from '../../lib/mysql-data.js'

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  let data = await MySQLData.getData()
  ...
}
```

```js
/* /src/lib/mysql-data.js */

import mysql from 'nodejs-mysql'

export async function getData() {
  const config = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'db_name',
  }

  const db = mysql.getInstance(config)
  let data
  await db
    .exec('select * from table_name')
    .then((rows) => data = rows)
    .catch((err) => console.warn(err))
  return data
}
```

Edit: I found it is also crashing (`TypeError: Str is not a function`) on build with another module: [@supercharge/strings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@supercharge/strings) which I'm using in a component, leading me to think its all about how I'm using these.

```js
---
const {  text } = Astro.props
import Str from '@supercharge/strings'
---
<div>
  <a href={url}>
    <p>{Str(text).words().slice(0,12).join(" ")} ...</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

After (much) more experimentation, I realize there are two issues:

1. I was able to reproduce the same `mysql.getInstance is not a function` error in MySQL outside of Astro (using express). So it is related to the https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodejs-mysql package. Switching to https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2 fixed the issue.
2. While I was able to use mysql2 without issue, another package https://www.npmjs.com/package/@supercharge/strings resulted in a similar error `TypeError: Str is not a function` making me again think there is something I'm missing about how/what Astro is able to import.

Comment: According to their Github it is: `import { Str } from '@supercharge/strings'`

Comment: @madflow Thank you for noticing that. It doesn't appear to be the case with the MySQL package though.

Comment: You said you fixed the problem, by using another lib. "nodejs-mysql" has 5 stars on Github and was last updated 2016. This was way before SSR and ESM was no a real thing yet. It is just not ready for that, I supose.

Comment: Agree. Thanks for your help https://github.com/alsey/nodejs-mysql/issues/2